# DRY with URLs when unsetting one of multiple CSS background-images

Tags: css, background-image

I use multiple background images. Under certain rules, I want one of them not to show.

Of course, I don’t want to repeat the superordinate rule (i.e. the image URLs). I want to set one of them to `none`, while letting the others as-is (i.e. inherited from the less specific rule).

Unfortunately, something like `background-image: none, initial|auto|unset|inherit;` doesn’t work, because those keywords all have other uses or targets.

Is there a way to target a specific CSV item?
Is there a suitable keyword?
Or is there no way around repetition, now and in future CSS?

```css
div{ background-image: url(https://placekitten.com/200/300), url(https://placekitten.com/200/300); }
div:hover{ background-image: none, /*DRY→*/ url(https://placekitten.com/200/300) /*←DRY*/; }
```

```html
<div style="width:400px;height:300px;background-position:left -2em,right 2em;background-repeat:no-repeat;"></div>
```

Comment: Ran into it again. Scenario: general global class for button styling, specific class for button icon (both with background-images, but defined in different places). It’s cascading, sure, but aware stacking or addition would be great. Pseudo elements it is.

Answer (score 1):

CSS variables can help here

```css
div {
  --img:url(https://placekitten.com/200/300);
  background-image: 
    var(--img),
    var(--img);
}

div:hover {
  background-image:
    none, 
    var(--img);
}
```

```html
<div style="width:400px;height:300px;background-position:left -2em,right 2em;background-repeat:no-repeat;"></div>
```

Or inheritance with a pseudo element:

```css
.box {
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
  background-position: right 2em;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-image: url(https://placekitten.com/200/300);
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
}

.box::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom:0;
  background:inherit;
  background-position: left -2em;
}
.box:hover::before {
  content:none;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

Comment: Hey, good idea. IE support should be irrelevant. I actually thought of using a variable in the snippet in order not to repeat the placeholder URL. 

Comment: @dakab added another idea